# Flask form onchange this.form.submit() throws TypeError: 'HTMLString' object is not callable

Tags: javascript, python, flask, wtforms

I'd like to implement onchange="this.form.submit()" on a select field in a FlaskForm.

Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38003712/how-to-pass-parameters-on-onchange-of-html-select-with-flask-wtf) (I've not the rep to comment on that directly), but it's giving me an error.

My form field:

```
            {{form.hidden_tag()}}
            <table>
                {{ render_field(form.result_name(**{"onchange":"this.form.submit()"})) }}
```

form_macros.html:

```
    <tr {% if field.errors %} class="error" {% endif %}>
        <td>{{ field.label }}</td>
        <td>{{ field(**kwargs)|safe }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="error" >
        <td></td>
        <td>
            <ul>
                {% for error in field.errors %}
                    <li>{{ error }}</li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        </td>
    </tr>
{% endmacro %}
```

When I access the form get I the error:

````
  File "...\anaconda2\envs\flask3\lib\site-packages\jinja2\runtime.py", line 262, in call
    return __obj(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: 'HTMLString' object is not callable
127.0.0.1 - - [24/Oct/2019 12:55:52] "GET /drives/xdd_dev HTTP/1.1" 500 -```
````

Answer (score 0):

Finally tracked down a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18143961/flask-attributeerror-htmlstring-object-has-no-attribute-call) with an answer that worked for me.

This format gives me the onchange submit() behavior and no error:

`{{ render_field(form.result_name, onchange="this.form.submit()") }}`